# Running ARCHICAD project in VS C++ Express 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am learning archicad and trying to open an existing example from API Development Kit in VS Express C++ 2013. I have installed SDK 7.1. in order to 64 development as VS Express doesn't run it by default. I am having trouble to run the example. 
However, I installed all the necessary components and programs. This error window pops up all the time I try to run. I really have no clue how to make an archicad sample project run in VS C++ Express 2013.
The third line in Russian is translated as: "Impossible to find the designated folder". 
I copied the API DevKit folder into the VS Express folder, doesn't help. 
Please, help if someone faced such a problem or does all this stuff.

P.S. I need to run ArchiCAD in VS C++ Express. 
This is the print screen:

[image: Print screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a former Archicad API developer, I would definitely recommend you to use **Visual Studio 2005 Express**.This specific version (assuming you are developing for AC12 and above), is compatible with the API (I developed for AC13 and AC15, it worked fine). That is also recommended by Graphisoft itself.

for further information:
http://www.archicadwiki.com/Developer/Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20API%20DevKit#Getting_Started_with_the_API_DevKit

Comment: Sorry for late respond. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the encoding of APIdefs_Automate.h. If it is ANSI, it will fail. The encoding must be UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

For older archicad projects you had to use vs2010. For the new 21 they upgraded to vs2015. To use vs2015 in older projects you have to have vs2010 installed to use it's v100 platform toolset. Then when you open an older project with the new visual studio, it asks for upgrading the project, here say no and you are good to go.